# Finding and altering the bitmap used by the buddy allocator in Linux kernel 4+

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm new to the linux kernel and trying to alter the current buddy allocator for Linux and for that I'm trying to find where the bitmap is assigned to each `free_area` for each `zone` that the buddy allocator uses while assigning blocks.
From what I understand is that the `zone->free_area[order]` points to list of blocks of size 2<sup>order</sup>. Now I'm assuming such a mapping as it is mathematical may be hidden in a macro/function concealed some shift operation.

What I wish to do is find that and alter it to change the size of blocks for each free_area (to my knowledge there are 10 of those)
Any pointer on where I should be looking is appreciated.

Adding a picture for clarity - What I really need his where are these bitmaps defined to be in the size of 2<sup>order</sup>.
[image: Buddy allocation data structures]

PS: Also most the documentation I've found on this related to the linux kernel 2 and a lots of structuring has changed since but although by looking at the code it seems like the core logic is still intact and that's why it has been of some help on where to look in not where it is.